# Getting the java.lang.illegalMonitorStateException, how to fix it?

Tags: java, wait, synchronized, notify

I have this error "java.lang.illegalMonitorStateException" and I dont exactly know how to fix it. I know the notifyAll() seems to be the reason, though I tried several things like putting the synchronized block or something, though I'm not quite sure how to work with it. I'm used to put the word "synchronized" after the "public", but I cannot do that this time. 
Basically I need to wake up getNextMessage() function everytime there is a new message on the msgQueue in the meanwhile it's "blocked".

```
private LinkedList<NetClientSideMessage> msgQueue = new LinkedList<NetClientSideMessage>();


@Override
public ClientSideMessage getNextMessage() {
    //wait for messages
    if (hasNextMessage() == false)
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    // if connection is down, return null
    if (isConnected() == false)
        return null;

    return msgQueue.getFirst();

}

@Override
public boolean hasNextMessage() {
    // check if there are messages waiting in queue
    if (msgQueue.size() > 0) {
        notifyAll();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of wait() and notifyAll(). It's all explained there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You using `wait/notifyAll` without a lock! You simply can't do that. Adding a synchronized to the method declaration should fix it.

```
public synchronized ClientSideMessage getNextMessage() {
}

public synchronized boolean hasNextMessage() {
  ..
}
```

Comment: yeah this it it, I feel stupid. Didnt know I could add the synchronized .. Thank you !

Comment: @JRed: the API and all the other similar questions on this subject would have told you the same thing.